# Wrong conversion from dicom to grayscale in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

When i try to convert dicom to grayscale ,some slices have a problem due to outlier(if i remember the name correctly ) so like in the picture below. I have these bright pixels on the teeth but the rest of the slice is darker when compared to other slices in the same dicom series . I would appreciate any help to solve this problem.

```
 cv::Mat imgdcm(int(DCM_image->getWidth()), int(DCM_image->getHeight()), CV_16U,(ushort*)DCM_image->getOutputData(DCM_image->getOutputDataSize()) );
cv::normalize(imgdcm,imgdcm,0,65535,cv::NORM_MINMAX);
```

[image]

Comment: That's what normalizing does, by definition. It finds the minimum and maximum brightness, maps those to black and white respectively, and stretches the rest of the brightnesses between them. If you want comparable brightness levels across all your images, you might need to implement that yourself by finding the min/max across all the images. `cv::minMaxLoc` and `cv::normalize`'s `alpha` and `beta` parameters can help you there.

Comment: To avoid the effect of the outliers, you need a more robust way to estimate the range. For example, use the interdecile or interquartile instead of the full range, and enlarge the interval so obtained, to compensate.

Comment: Before you normalize have a look at a histogram of the image stack intensities. You can then filter out the areas of high density. After you have done that then noramlize the stack.

Comment: @YvesDaoust and what to do with outliers? Setting them higher value outliers to the maximum value of the interdecile and the lower one to the lowest value of the interdecile?

Comment: @Kaschi14: perform a linear rescaling and clamp the high and low values.